# How to access my SSH linux server from outside my home network

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

So I've been scouring the internet for days trying to figure this out and can't figure it out.

I know its going to be an easy one.

So I recently took an old desktop and loaded ubuntu server 12.04 on it.  My goal with this project is to create an area to host a few git repositories and maybe a simple webpage.

I've installed both the SSH and Apache2 packages and tried to configure them.  Right now I can log in from my laptop using ssh greg@0.0.0.0.0 but only while I am on the same network.  Once I leave the house I get a timeout error.

So 2 things I would like to get at right now.

1. How to configure the SSH to allow me to access the server from outside the network.
2. Get my host name on the server so logins will be greg@hostname instead of greg@0.0.0

   (I've done sudo hostname and changed the etc/hostname file and no results)

Thanks guys.

Comment: You need to open ports 22 and 80 through your router (although I'd recommend you change the port you're using for SSH to something non-standard). Getting access from outside will be easier if you set up a DNS entry for it. Both these things are off-topic for SO. Try asking on [su]

Comment: offtopic here, but make sure your server computer has accessible ports (might be blocked by router/firewall/etc) then use your server's external ip address,

Comment: Sorry guys, i reposted it on super user.  thanks for the feedback

Comment: [Same question](http://superuser.com/questions/648615/cant-access-my-ssh-linux-server-when-outside-network) on [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The timeout external to your home network occurs because the IP you specified will be routed elsewhere on external networks.

As others have indicated, you need to configure port forwarding on your router (external interface) to the SSH server.  You can either use the standard port (22) or any alternative port (something above 1024).  For the webserver you will need to set the port forwarding from port 80 on the external interface to your server and maybe port 443 if you want to include SSL/TLS connections.

I also recommend using the SSH config file (~/.ssh/config) to make it easier when making either an internal or external connection.  Add something like this:

```
Host serverext
Hostname 1.2.3.4
User greg
Port 22

Host serverint
Hostname 192.168.1.10
User greg
Port 22
```

Change the Hostname for the serverext config to the IP address of your Internet connection.  If you use a non-standard port for the external SSH connections then change the port field for serverext to match that.

Change the Hostname for the serverint config to the internal IP address for that server on your network.

Once this is configured, in conjunction with the port forwarding you will be able to use "ssh serverint" to connect to your server when you're at home and "ssh serverext" to connect to it when you're somewhere else.

It is possible to include advanced configuration options through the SSH configuration file, such as port tunneling and websocket connections.  In the past I've done things like that and redirecting SSH connections through SOCKS proxy servers.  I've even had it run through Tor, but it is very slow.

Comment: Hi Ben, I stuck into the situation that, there's a computer behind a router and I don't have any rights to config the router, but I have a DDNS for it and I have a server under my control. Then how can I access my computer behind in the local network from outside? Many thanks!

Comment: Without access to the router you can't configure port forwarding to any of the systems on that network.  These things are often referred to as gateways for a reason.

Comment: Bens answer is not completely accurate in regards to your inability to open ports on a router you do not control. Most of the options however, are too ridiculous for most intents and purposes to do though and create redundancy in what you are doing. You could tunnel through your non-controlled router via openvpn or any other vpn protocol on port 443 into a cloud instance/ cloud server, and have that server redirect your connection to a new public and open IP address. Then you could run your home server through the local vpn, into the cloud instance, out to the real internet with a static ip.

Comment: I coded this service. I am having all my devices for almost 3 years. I just gave it nice look and make it public and free.
check https://mylinuz.com